How can I delete WooCommerce webhooks without leaving them disabled?
I'm trying to delete all WooCommerce webhooks, but after doing so they still appear as "Disabled" in the advanced settings -> webhooks interface.
I've been trying to do this:
$webhook_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT webhook_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_webhooks");
foreach( $webhook_ids as $webhook_id )
{
    // Get the webhook
    $webhook = new \WC_Webhook( $webhook_id );

    // Delete the webhook
    $webhook->delete( TRUE ); // true to force delete
}

I've even tried doing this:
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_wc_webhooks");

And I've also tried doing this:
$webhook_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT webhook_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_webhooks");
foreach( $webhook_ids as $webhook_id )
{
    // Get the webhook
    $webhook = new \WC_Webhook( $webhook_id );

    // Delete the webhook
    $webhook->delete( TRUE ); // true to force delete

    $WC_Webhook_Data_Store = new \WC_Webhook_Data_Store();
    $WC_Webhook_Data_Store->delete( $webhook );
}

No matter what I do, the result is the same. A list of "Disabled" webhooks in the admin area. What's interesting is that the wp_wc_webhooks table is empty. I know there is a cache, but I was under the impression that using the delete method of the WC_Webhook_Data_Store should clear it.
What can I do to get rid of these pesky "Disabled" webhooks?

I didn't mention that I'm trying to delete the webhooks from code that is called through WP CLI, but the answer came by using a WooCommerce CLI command:
$webhook_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT webhook_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_webhooks");
foreach( $webhook_ids as $webhook_id )
{
    \WP_CLI::runcommand('wc webhook delete ' . $webhook_id . ' --force=true --user=93062220');
}

It would still be nice to know how to do this if CLI wasn't available, but this was the answer to my question.
